# How to use .withoutSizeLimit in Akka-http (client) HttpRequest?

Tags: akka-http

I'm using Akka 2.4.7 to read a web resource that is essentially a stream of JSON objects, delimited with newlines. The stream is practically unlimited in size.

When around 8MB has been consumed, I get an exception:

```
[error] (run-main-0) EntityStreamSizeException: actual entity size (None) exceeded content length limit (8388608 bytes)! You can configure this by setting `akka.http.[server|client].parsing.max-content-length` or calling `HttpEntity.withSizeLimit` before materializing the dataBytes stream.
```

The "actual entity size (None)" seems a bit funny, but my real question is, how to use the `HttpEntity.withSizeLimit` (or in my case, rather `.withoutSizeLimit` that should be there, as well).

My request code is like this:

```
val chunks_src: Source[ByteString,_] = Source.single(req)
  .via(connection)
  .flatMapConcat( _.entity.dataBytes )
```

I tried adding a `.map( (x: HttpResponse) => x.withoutSizeLimit )`, but it does not compile. What's the role of the `HttpEntity` when doing client side programming, anyways?

I can change the global config, but that's kind of missing the point. I'd like to flag "no limits" only for a particular request.

As a further question, I understand the need for a `max-content-length` on the server side, but why affect the client?

References:

- Akka 2.4.7: [Limiting message entity length](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/common/http-model.html#Limiting_message_entity_length)
- Akka 2.4.7: [HttpEntity](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/common/http-model.html#HttpEntity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm far from an expert on this topic, but it would seem you need to add the `.withoutSizeLimit()` to the entity like:

```
Source.single(req)
  .via(connection)
  .flatMapConcat( _.entity.withoutSizeLimit().dataBytes )
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm no longer working actively on that code. Hopefully others find this useful.